# Llenar un select en react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Estoy intentando cargar un *select* dentro de un modal, para eso he creado un state donde guardo los datos que obtengo de una api y que son los que quiero mostrar pero al momento de recorrerlos para insertarlos en el `<option>` no se reflejan en pantalla, pero tampoco obtengo ningún error.

¿Alguien me puede orientar en como hacerlo ?

STATE:

```
const [departamento, setDepartamento] = useState([]);  //array de datos
```

PETICIÓN:

```
const peticionGetDep = async () => {
      let urlDep = "https://localhost:44321/api/Department";

     await axios
    .get(urlDep, { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` } })
    .then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data);
    setDepartamento(JSON.parse(response.data));    //cambio el state para almacenar los datos
    console.log(departamento);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
  };
```

MODAL:

```
<ModalBody>
  <div className="form-group">          
    <label>Departamento: </label>
    <select name="departmentId" className="form-control">
      {departamento.map((dpto) => {                   //recorro el state y muestro datos
        <option key={dpto.id} value={dpto.id}>
          {dpto.name}
        </option>;
      })}
    </select>            
  </div>
</ModalBody>
```

Comment: Si no tienes error es muy probable que tu función axios este bien. Hace falta el código completo de tu modal, lo mas posible es que ahí este el error. La función que muestras que hace el map debe ir dentro de un hook `useEffect` que corra cada vez que haya cambios en Departamento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema radica en que falta un return, por eso no da error, ya que obtengo los datos pero no hago nada con ellos. la función con el select quedaría así:

```
          <select
            id="comboDepartamento"
            name="departmentId"
            className="form-control"
          >
            {departamento.map((dpto) => {
              return (
                <option key={dpto.id} value={dpto.id}>
                  {dpto.name}
                </option>
              );
            })}
          </select>
```

Comment: Recuerda aceptar tu respuesta como correcta, de esta manea otros sabrán que esta respuesta dio solución a tu problema.